# Python Pandas and Generator to Process Lines in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, generator

Hoping that this is an allowable SO question but I am hoping to get some advice on how to convert the below code which processes lines in a file to produce a dataframe into one that uses generators and yields because this implementation using list and append is far too slow.

Here is the solution I came up with but I was really hoping to avoid using very slow lists and append operation. I was hoping for cool generator and yield solution instead but not comfortable enough yet working with generators.

Sample lines in file:

```
"USNC3255","27","US","NC","LANDS   END","72305006","KNJM","KNCA","KNKT","T72305006","","","NCC031","NCZ095","","545","28594","America/New_York","34.65266","-77.07661","7","RDU","893727","
"USNC3256","27","US","NC","LANDSDOWN","72314058","KEHO","KAKH","KIPJ","T72314058","","","NCC045","NCZ068","sc007","517","28150","America/New_York","35.29374","-81.46537","797","CLT","317845","
```

Current Solution:

```
def parse_file(filename):

    newline = []

    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for row in reader:
            newline.append([s.strip('"') for s in row[:-1]])
    df = pd.DataFrame(newline)
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: nan if len(x) == 0 else x).astype(object)
    return df

df = parse_file(filename)
```

Output is just a dataframe with 23 columns and two rows if used against the sample lines above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem with your file is that each line ends with `,"`. This confuses the parser. If you can remove the trailing comma and quotation mark, you can use the regular parser.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
with open('example.txt') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read().replace(',"\n', '\n')
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None)
```

This is what I get:

```
         0   1   2   3            4         5     6     7     8          9   \
0  USNC3255  27  US  NC  LANDS   END  72305006  KNJM  KNCA  KNKT  T72305006   
1  USNC3256  27  US  NC    LANDSDOWN  72314058  KEHO  KAKH  KIPJ  T72314058   

     ...          13     14   15     16                17        18        19  \
0    ...      NCZ095    NaN  545  28594  America/New_York  34.65266 -77.07661   
1    ...      NCZ068  sc007  517  28150  America/New_York  35.29374 -81.46537   

    20   21      22  
0    7  RDU  893727  
1  797  CLT  317845  

[2 rows x 23 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately cleaning the original file is not an option.

Comment: @prometheus2305 Why not? I haven't changed the original file's contents; they are the same on disk. I've only changed what's in my program's memory.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood. This worked perfectly and I feel like an idiot. Thanks so much.